# How do you convert a buffer of hexadecimals to an array of hexadecimals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, buffer

```
var file = randomAccessFile('gen.mp3')

    file.read(0, 5, function(err, buffer) {
      console.log(buffer) 

    for (const value of buffer.values()) {
      console.log(value);
    }

    file.close(function() {
    console.log('file is closed')

       })
    })
```

The first output is:

```
<Buffer 49 44 33 03 00>
```

and the second:

```
73
68
51
3
0
```

I need an array, or some other data structure, where I can access the values of the first output individually. How would I do that? Why does the second output convert the hexadecimal to decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just access the buffer with `[index]`. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_index

You can print the values in hex if you want as well.

```
var file = randomAccessFile('gen.mp3')

file.read(0, 5, function(err, buffer) {
  console.log(buffer) 
  console.log(buffer[0]); // prints decimal
  console.log(buffer[0].toString(16)); //prints hexadecimal
  file.close(function() {
       console.log('file is closed')
  })
})
```